# Push data from console.log to html

Tags: javascript, firebase, console, fitbit

```
const access_token = ""


fetch('https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json', {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token}
})
.then(response => response.json())
//.then(json => console.log(json))
.then((out) =>
{ 
   
    console.log(out.data);
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML=out.data;
    
})
```

hi, I have been trying to fetch wep API using the above js code. i have successfully fetched the data inside my debug console but now I want to fetch inside my firebase. Can someone help with this. For security purpose i removed the access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code seems OK. Either your access token is not correct, or the JSON object  you receive has no "data" key.

If I'm on the right page, it seems that you should use "out.user" instead of "out.data":
https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/user/get-profile/

Comment: The one that I found on my debug console after changed it to "out.user" is looks like this {age: 17, ambassador: false, autoStrideEnabled: true, avatar: 'https://static0.fitbit.com/images/profile/defaultProfile_100.png', avatar150: 'https://static0.fitbit.com/images/profile/defaultProfile_150.png', …}

yet still in html page the output shows [object Object]

Comment: It's normal that it show as "[object Object]" in HTML. If you want to display it like this, you have to print it as a string with JSON.stringify(out).

Comment: Alright, thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the `out.data` is string not an array or object.

Comment: string in {} . if i push the data using  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML=out.user; it shows  [object Object]

Comment: you can't render object data type you can only render specific data like out.data.title or out.data.description or what ever you get from your api.

Comment: tell me if you need an example.

Comment: i just tried using out.data.title and yes it worked for me. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: your welcome  you can upvote my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Another quick question, is it possible to push console.log to firebase? 

Comment: yes you can, by doing so you can see fetched api data in client's console but why you wanna do so ?

Comment: okay, i am developing a mobile and web application. it is fitness monitoring system using fitbit web API. initial plan is to fetch API from mobile to firebase then from firebase to web. But I'm having trouble in connecting fitbit wep API to mobile app. So now if I able to put the data into firebase mobile application users also can view the data.

Comment: i don't have my expertise in firebase sorry for that 